# Having A Problem With If Statements In Python

Tags: python, if-statement

My goal is to have something like this:

```
x = 201
if x >= 100 <= 200: 
    print(x)
else:
    print('Less Than 100 Or More Than 200')
```

but it doesn't work:

output: `201`

basically anything smaller than or equal 100 and anything smaller or equal 200

Would this be possible?

Comment: Bad syntax.  Try if (x >= 100  and x <= 200):

Comment: I wish that was a feature too :/. You have to do `x >= 100 and x <= 200`

Comment: Or, since Python allows for comparison chaining, `100 <= x <= 200`.

Comment: `100 <= x <= 200`. You just have the operands in the wrong order. Your expression is equivalent to `x >= 100 and 100 <= 200`; since `100 <= 200` is *always* true, it can be dropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you wanna do this :

```
x = 201
if  100<= x <= 200: 
    print(x)
else:
    print('Less Than 100 Or More Than 200')
```

Answer (score 3):

Python has comparison chaining, written the same way as in mathematical notation:

```
if 100 <= x <= 200:
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if 100 <= x and x <= 200:
```

(Though if the expression `x` has side effects it will be evaluated twice in the second example but only once in the first.)